# Usage of Split() function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to code in pyspark using Jupiter Notebook.
Facing issue while using split() function
Dataframe i am using

```
import_csv=spark.read.csv("F:\\Learning\\PySpark\\DATA\\Iris.csv",header="true")
import_csv.show()
import_csv=spark.read.csv("F:\\Learning\\PySpark\\DATA\\Iris.csv",header="true")
import_csv.show()
+---+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| Id|SepalLengthCm|SepalWidthCm|PetalLengthCm|PetalWidthCm|    Species|
+---+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|  1|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  2|          4.9|         3.0|          1.4|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  3|          4.7|         3.2|          1.3|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  4|          4.6|         3.1|          1.5|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  5|          5.0|         3.6|          1.4|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  6|          5.4|         3.9|          1.7|         0.4|Iris-setosa|
|  7|          4.6|         3.4|          1.4|         0.3|Iris-setosa|
|  8|          5.0|         3.4|          1.5|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
|  9|          4.4|         2.9|          1.4|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
| 10|          4.9|         3.1|          1.5|         0.1|Iris-setosa|
| 11|          5.4|         3.7|          1.5|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
| 12|          4.8|         3.4|          1.6|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
| 13|          4.8|         3.0|          1.4|         0.1|Iris-setosa|
| 14|          4.3|         3.0|          1.1|         0.1|Iris-setosa|
| 15|          5.8|         4.0|          1.2|         0.2|Iris-setosa|
| 16|          5.7|         4.4|          1.5|         0.4|Iris-setosa|
| 17|          5.4|         3.9|          1.3|         0.4|Iris-setosa|
| 18|          5.1|         3.5|          1.4|         0.3|Iris-setosa|
| 19|          5.7|         3.8|          1.7|         0.3|Iris-setosa|
| 20|          5.1|         3.8|          1.5|         0.3|Iris-setosa|
+---+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

trying to split each line of RDD on the basis of "," (comma)

```
csv_split= import_csv.rdd.map(lambda var1: var1.split(','))
print(csv_split.collect())
```

Getting error as **'split' is not in list**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 65.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 65.0 (TID 65, DESKTOP-NPEMBC9, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1595, in __getattr__
    idx = self.__fields__.index(item)
ValueError: 'split' is not in list
```

Comment: bro, you var1 is a rdd row, not a comma seperated string,the `spar.read.csv()` method already done it for you, splitting the csv and storing it in your spark dataframe `import_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

In Spark split() is used to split/break a string/column into multiple based on some identifier and returns a List/ AttayType

```
df_b = spark.createDataFrame([('1','ABC-07-DEF')],[ "ID","col1"])
df_b = df_b.withColumn('post_split', F.split(F.col('col1'), "-"))
df_b.show()

+---+----------+--------------+
| ID|      col1|    post_split|
+---+----------+--------------+
|  1|ABC-07-DEF|[ABC, 07, DEF]|
+---+----------+--------------+
```

Further you can use **getItem()** in order to extract the columns from that Arry column as below

```
df_b = df_b.withColumn('split_col1', F.col('post_split').getItem(0)).withColumn('split_col2', F.col('post_split').getItem(1)).withColumn('split_col3', F.col('post_split').getItem(2))
df_b.show()

+---+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
| ID|      col1|    post_split|split_col1|split_col2|split_col3|
+---+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1|ABC-07-DEF|[ABC, 07, DEF]|       ABC|        07|       DEF|
+---+----------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+
```